# unable connect flask web with nginx in container

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

the environment:
ubuntu docker and container(not previliged, port=6000->8080), flask(serve.py), gunicorn, nginx. server ip:123.456.789.101

I want to other people can access the web(123.456.789.101:6000) which running in the docker container, and visit the static imagins(123.456.789.101:6000/static/1.jpg).

When i only use flask and gunicorn, and run `guincorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 serve:app`, i can access the web(123.456.789.101:6000) successful.

But if i use nginx proxy, it failed. 
detail as follow:

first, `$ gunicorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:8080 serve:app`, success, i can curl it in container system.

second, $ `service nginx start`, and load the conf file in site-enables.

nginx conf detail:

```
server {
        listen 6000;
        server_name 123.456.789.101;

         location / {
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                 proxy_redirect     off;
                 proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
         }
         location /static/ {
                root /www;
                expires 30d;
         }
}
```

Final, it failed. I can't access the web(123.456.789.101:6000).

For find what wrong, i try run `gunicorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:8080 serve:app`, and change the nginx conf file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

         location / {
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                 proxy_redirect     off;
                 proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
         }
         location /static/ {
                root /www;
                expires 30d;
         }
}
```

and `curl 127.0.0.1` in container system. it success. it means nginx can work, it can map 80 to 8080.

So, what wrong, how can i solve it. Thanks.

Comment: whats your command for running docker? are you exposing ports outside?

Comment: i have not authority to run the docker. (it means the server be charged by someone, but i can make requests.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i success. 
it's a big mistake in the nginx conf file.
detail follow:

1,run  `guincorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 serve:app` (this port at random, but can't use already using port)

2,run `service nginx start`
nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name _;# _ = 0.0.0.0
     location / {
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
             proxy_redirect     off;
             proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
             proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
     }
     location /static/ {
            root /www;
            expires 30d;
     }
}
```

i comprehend this process:
visit web 123.456.789.101:6000, the docker host server(maybe also a nginx run in host server) will map ip to the docker container server 172.17.0.1:8080, and next the nginx will map ip to 127.0.0.1:8000, finally gunicorn flask answer.

so, i only use nginx to listen the port 0.0.0.0:8080, this is why, i don't use nginx only gunicorn can work. This nginx like a medium.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application:

Try Running into Docker
 gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 serve:app

If you are using Dockerfile:
    expose 8080
If you are using docker-compose.yml
    expose:
      - "8080"

Nginx Configuration (Replace DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP): 


server {
         listen 6000;
         server_name 123.456.789.101;

         location / {
                 proxy_pass http://DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP:8080;
                 proxy_redirect     off;
                 proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
         }
         location /static/ {
                root /www;
                expires 30d;
         }
}
```

Comment: this answer is useful if you added descriptions

Comment: OK I'll add description But What should not clear can you mention so that I modify....

Comment: very thanks. what do you mean about DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP? 127.0.0.1 ? 172.17.0.5? Because i can't use ifconfig in the container, so i guess the ip:172.17.0.5(try 172.17.0.1~4, show me "cannot bind").

Comment: And i don't know how to verify the conf, because if i only run gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8080, i can visit the web. so i start nginx , i don't know whether it working.

Comment: I don't the conf nginx about images path is't right?
my images in local system path:/www/static/1.jpg
but i try http://123.456.789.101:6000/static/1.jpg, the page show me 404 not found.
by the way, i run  'chmod -R 755 /www', and change 'user root' in nginx.conf